# Convert some fields of array of objects to json data in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects as mentioned below,

```
  var arraydata =[
{ id:1, name:"Abraham", age:20,gender:"male"},
{ id:2, name:"Annie", age:25,gender:"female"},
{ id:3, name:"Ryan", age:40,gender:"male"},
{ id:4, name:"Wayne", age:31,gender:"male"},
{ id:5, name:"Paul", age:45,gender:"male"}
];
```

how to convert this to a JSON data, which has only "id" and "name" field?

Comment: with new objects, or in situ?

Comment: with new object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

syntax is wrong `age=20,gender="male"` change it to `age:20,gender:"male"`

```js
var arraydata =[
{ id:1, name:"Abraham", age: 20, gender:"male"},
{ id:2, name:"Annie", age: 25, gender:"female"},
{ id:3, name:"Ryan", age: 28, gender:"male"},
{ id:4, name:"Wayne", age: 19, gender:"male"},
{ id:5, name:"Paul", age: 45,gender:"male"}
];
var ans= arraydata.map(function(a){
return {id:a.id,name:a.name};
})
console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arraydata =[
{ id:1, name:"Abraham", age: 20, gender: "male"},
{ id:2, name:"Annie", age: 25, gender: "female"},
{ id:3, name:"Ryan", age: 28, gender: "male"},
{ id:4, name:"Wayne", age: 19, gender: "male"},
{ id:5, name:"Paul", age: 45, gender: "male"}
];


var _ = arraydata.map(function(item) {
    return { id: item.id, name: item.name };
});

var jsonData = JSON.stringify(_);

console.log(jsonData);
```

You can of course chain together the two steps.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markwill/de7092o7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`delete operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) which remove a property from an object.

```js
  var arraydata = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Abraham",
    age : 20,
    gender : "male"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Annie",
    age : 25,
    gender : "female"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Ryan",
    age : 40,
    gender : "male"
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: "Wayne",
    age : 31,
    gender : "male"
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: "Paul",
    age : 45,
    gender : "male"
  }];

arraydata.forEach(function(item){ delete item.age; delete item.gender });

  console.log(arraydata);
```